# List users from specific groups

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, arraylist, report

Good morning all,

I am currentlycovering my line manager. And I need to modify an existing to VBScript, to pull users from specific groups in AD (Commercial, Finance, HR, IT, Marketing, Operations, and Property):

```
Const ForReading = 1,ForWriting = 2,ForAppending = 8
StartFilename = "AD groups.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(StartFilename,ForAppending, True)

strDomainName = inputbox("Enter Domain Name","AD Billing","") 

Set objDomain = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomainName)

For each objDomainObject in objDomain
If objDomainObject.class = "Group" Then
Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://"& strDomainName & "/" & objDomainObject.Name)
objTextFile.writeline("")
objTextFile.writeline("Domain: " & strDomainName & "   Group: " & objDomainObject.Name)
objTextFile.writeline("")
Set objMemberList = objGroup.Members
For Each objGroupMember In objMemberList
Set objMember = objGroupMember
objTextFile.writeline ("Group member: " & objMember.Name)
Next
End If
Next
objTextFile.close
```

Any help is greatly appriciated
Kind regards

Justin

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `If` after the `If` where you find out that it's a `Group`, but instead of comparing on the `class`, compare on the `Name.

So amending your original code it would be something like this:

```
Const ForReading = 1,ForWriting = 2,ForAppending = 8
StartFilename = "AD groups.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(StartFilename,ForAppending, True)

strDomainName = inputbox("Enter Domain Name","AD Billing","") 
strGroupName =  inputbox("Enter Group Name","AD Billing","") 

Set objDomain = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomainName)

For each objDomainObject in objDomain
    If objDomainObject.class = "Group" Then
        If objDomainObject.Name = strGroupName Then
            Set objGroup = GetObject("WinNT://"& strDomainName & "/" & objDomainObject.Name)
            objTextFile.writeline("")
            objTextFile.writeline("Domain: " & strDomainName & "   Group: " & objDomainObject.Name)
            objTextFile.writeline("")
            Set objMemberList = objGroup.Members
            For Each objGroupMember In objMemberList
                Set objMember = objGroupMember
                objTextFile.writeline ("Group member: " & objMember.Name)
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
objTextFile.close
```

I assumed that you wanted to ask each time which group using a `InputBox`, otherwise you could hardcode those values in the `If` statement as
`If objDomainObject.Name = "Commercial" Or objDomainObject.Name = "Finance" Or .... Then`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this above the next statement (To reenumerate the objects after being in a container/OU.):

```
If objDomainObject.Class = "organizationalUnit" Or 
   objDomainObject.Class = "container" Then
        enumMembers (objMember)
End If
```